# Impedir que uma aplicação Android seja 'minimizada'

Tags: android

Não sei se minimizar seria a palavra correta, creio que não... Por favor me corrijam.

Tenho uma aplicação e quero impedir alguém de minimizar ela usando o botão Home, se alguém apertar o Home, a aplicação será finalizada por completo, incluindo todas as Activity que foram abertas, e também preciso que execute um método quando essa aplicação for finalizada nestes termos...

Como fazer?

Edit: É uma aplicação que o usuário pode selecionar arquivos para proteger contra acesso de outros aplicativos, estes arquivos protegidos podem ser acessados somente pela minha aplicação (ela pede login), enquanto minha aplicação está em execução os arquivos estão desprotegidos, pois ela necessita de 'desproteger' eles para poder ler, muitos leigos clicam no botão Home e acha que a aplicação foi finalizada, quero evitar isto, quero evitar que os arquivos continuem desprotegidos pq a aplicação ainda está em execução, e quero evitar que uma outra pessoa pegue o celular do usuario e acabe ganhando acesso a aplicação e aos arquivos porque simplesmente ele está aberto

Comment: Se você necessita mesmos de fazer isso, permita-me sugerir que deve repensar o desenho da sua aplicação, pois isso vai contra a forma de programar para android.

Comment: sim eu preciso fazer isso, é um aplicativo que protege alguns arquivos, esses arquivos protegidos podem ser acessados somente pela aplicação, e a aplicação pede LOGIN, sim eu preciso que a aplicação seja morta neste caso

Comment: a maioria das pessoas leigas não fecham a aplicação, simplesmente clicam no botão Home, minha aplicação precisa da máxima de segurança. Acabei de receber voto negativo por causa disso

Comment: @ramaral editei o post mencionando o porque disto. Já vi meus concorrentes fazendo o mesmo, só queria saber como, se tiver outra maneira também é bom

Comment: A forma correta de isso ser feito é controlar o chamado [*Activity Lifecycle*](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), nos momentos de [*Stopping and Restarting an Activity*](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android é particularmente desenhado para fazer `pause` a uma aplicação quando o botão de `home` é usado.

Por causa disso, existem dois métodos para gerir o que deve acontecer quando alguém usa o `home` ou navega para fora da aplicação: [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) e [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29).

Podes saber mais sobre o funcionamento dos mesmos em [Pausing and Resuming an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

A título de exemplo, podes fazer uma classe tua que extende a `Activity` de forma a realizares determinadas tarefas quando a aplicação entra em `pause`:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // raio, usaram o botão 'home', deixa-me proteger os ficheiros!
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // epá, utilizador voltou, deixa desproteger os ficheiro!
    }
}

public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity {
    // ...
}
```

Também para o teu caso, poderá ser util definir [`android:clearTaskOnlaunch="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) para que as `activities` sejam terminadas quando alguém volta para a aplicação.

---

## Verificar se aplicação em *background*

Pode ser util também saber se a aplicação está a ir para *background*, o que nos permite reagir de uma forma mais acertiva.

A função em baixo permite verificar se a aplicação se encontra a ir para *background*. A mesma pode ser chamada no método `onPause()` de todas as `Activity` da aplicação:

```
 /**
   * Verifica se o aplicativo está sendo enviado para segundo plano
   * (ou seja, para trás da atividade de outra aplicação).       * 
   *
   * @param context O contexto
   * @return <code>true</code> se outro aplicativo vai estar acima deste.
   */
  public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
      if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

A função carece permissões extra pelo que deverás no teu `AndroidManifest.xml` incluir o seguinte:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

<sup>Créditos desta função para o utilizador @peceps no SOEN [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9313658/352449).</sup>

Comment: eu tinha pensado nisso, mas como eu faria no caso do Login?

Comment: Dado a aplicação gerir informação sensivel, penso que o ideal será terminar o login e forçar o mesmo no arranque e/ou re-arranque da aplicação. Mas isso é uma consideração a ter no design da aplicação e naquilo que se pretende para a mesma.

Comment: no caso não deu certo.. onPause é chamado com dialogs também, e onStop é chamado depois que chama outras Activity

Comment: não há como verificar se a aplicação está em background?

Comment: Existe sim, o método `onPause()` é chamado quando a aplicação vai para _background_.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta uma função que verifica a questão do _background_.

Comment: segundo a doc do Android, isso é para ser usado somente para Debug, creio que devo ter problemas com a play store se usar isso

Comment: devia haver algum onBackground no android, ta fazendo muita falta aqui... Se eu uso onPause e onResume não da certo, pois eles são afetados quando há mudanças de activity, não sei o que meu concorrente fez, mas quando aperto o botão home no app dele, o app simplesmente é morto e nem se quer aparece naquela listinha de cache do Android 4.0+ (quando seguramos o home)

Comment: O método [`getRunningTasks(int maxNum)`, foi depreciado na API level 21 (LOLLIPOP)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)), por questões de segurança, pela possibilidade de vazar informações pessoais a aplicativos de terceiros. (Se for utilizar este método esteja consciente que ela não será suportada para futuras versões Android).